# Does html input support drag & drop from zip folder?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I implemented a drag & drop functionality in a React component with a HTML input box. It works perfectly, it receives the file and uploads it to Amazon S3, checking if the file type is compatible with the one specified from props.

The problem occurs when dragging a file from a ZIP file. I console.loggued the resultant file object, and the only difference with a file dragged from a desktop folder is the size (From ZIP file => size = 0).

When I'm dragging the file, is there a way to recognize that it comes from a ZIP file so it waits until the file has finished uploading to the input? Also, how could I check if the file has finished uploading?

The function that receives the file and checks it:

```
export default function(e, onUpload, acceptedTypes) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
  if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
    if (isAcceptedType(file, acceptedTypes)) {
      onUpload(file)
    }
  }
}
```

I forgot to mention initially, that when I drop a file in the input, it gets "uploaded" to S3 immediately, but with size 0 (Since it comes from a ZIP file), so the site recognizes it as a file, but when I'm trying to see the content it says error.

Thank you!

Comment: Try it and see if it works.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ it doesn't. I forgot to mention that. I dropped it, the input receives it and sends it immediatly, so when I'm checking the file, it shows error.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "zip folder". There are zip files, which some applications display as folders to ease the use of zip files. I'm thinking that the application does the unzipping in its drop event, and that the file input is not seen as a valid drop target. That's why it's not uploading the file: there's no file in the clipboard for it to upload.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Comment: In the end I blocked the html input if the file dragged and dropped has a size of 0 bytes. Yes, I messed up the question. Thank you guys I'll try to improve my writing from now on. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this workaround, as I also haven't found an actual solution:

```
// when dropped from a zip only one file gets recognized
if(droppedFiles.length === 1) {
  const timeTolerance = 10;
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const isAutoGenerated = now - file.lastModified < timeTolerance;
  if (file.size === 0 && isAutoGenerated) {
    return false; // invalid file
  }
}
```

Because the `lastModified` is so close to the current time it's most likely automatically generated and in combination with the size of 0 I identify it as an placeholder file.